# How would I get it to get the currentRow of that specific record?

Tags: coldfusion

I'm trying to get the currentrow record when I submit the form 
for that specific row. 
When I dump to see what the form is getting It still gets all the rows 
in the query.
This is what I get when I click on the 'submit1', (I crop the image)
[image]
Mush2 and Mush3 have the exact record count.

How would I get it to get the currentRow of that specific record?
To get it that it will only get me the txtresponseid[x] of the record I submitted.

```
<form method="post" action="cse_execoffice_pending.cfm" name="review_comments">
<cfoutput>
<input type="hidden" name="txtApprovedBy" value="#GetCurrentUser.emp_id#">
<!-- count the records that come in from the pending -->
<input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#Mush2.CurrentRow#">
</cfoutput>
<cfoutput query="Mush3">

        <div class="comments_approvaldecision">
            <p>

            <CFDUMP VAR=#response_id#>
            <input type="hidden" name="txtResponseID#CurrentRow#" value="#response_id#">
            <input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#CurrentRow#" id="approve#CurrentRow#" value="1" checked="checked"> <label for="approve#CurrentRow#">Approve</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#CurrentRow#" id="deny#CurrentRow#" value="2"> <label for="deny#CurrentRow#">Deny</label>
            </p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>
            <input type="radio" name="star#mush3.CurrentRow#" id="givestar#CurrentRow#" value="0" checked="checked"> <label for="givestar#CurrentRow#"></i> Give Star!</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="star#mush3.CurrentRow#" id="denystar#CurrentRow#" value="1"> <label for="denystar#CurrentRow#"></i> No Star</label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="clearfloat<cfif (#commentpositive# eq '')> hideempty</cfif>"><img src="positive.gif" width="10" height="10"> Positive Comments:<br>
        <cfset reReplaceCommentpositive = reReplace(commentpositive, '<br>', '', 'ALL')>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentPositive#CurrentRow#">#reReplaceCommentpositive#</textarea></div>
        <div class="clearfloat<cfif (#commentnegative# eq '')> hideempty</cfif>"><img src="negative.gif" width="10" height="10"> Negative Comments:<br>
        <cfset reReplaceCommentnegative = reReplace(commentnegative, '<br>', '', 'ALL')>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentNegative#CurrentRow#">#reReplaceCommentnegative#</textarea></div>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit">
</cfoutput>

<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>

</cfif><!--- /cfif FormSubmit eq "FormNotSubmitted" --->
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently your page is just one big form, with the looping of `mush3` inside the form.

To Submit each separately, create and end a `<form>` in each iteration of the loop:

```
<cfoutput query="Mush3">
    <form method="post" action="cse_execoffice_pending.cfm" name="review_comments#CurrentRow#">

    ... form data....
    <input type="submit" name="Submit1" value="Submit#CurrentRow#">
    </form>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: would i still be able to have the other <input submit...> outside to submit all ?

Comment: No, it's either one form or many. The way you have it in the question you have many submit buttons, but they all do the exact same thing....If you want to submit them all at once, how do you even have a concept of "current row"? They're ALL current. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The last time I did something like this, I used the following approach.  First, on my form, I would include the current value as a hidden field.  Note that the field names include an indentier as do the field names in the question.

```
<cfoutput query="ExistingRecords">
<tr align="left">
<th>Name</th>
<td>
<input type="hidden" name="OldName#doctorid#" value="#name#" />
<cfinput type="text" 
name="name#doctorid#" 
value="#name#" size="50" onChange="this.value=Trim(this.value);" maxlength="100">
</td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Then I identified records to update.

```
<cfloop list="#form.fieldnames#" index="ThisElement">
<cfscript>
UpdateRecord = false;

if (some stuff about new records) {
} // new name??

else if (left(ThisElement, 7) == "oldname"){
ThisId = RemoveChars(ThisElement, 1, 7);
ThisOldName = form["OldName" & ThisId];
ThisName = safetext(form["Name" & ThisId]);

if (Compare(ThisName, ThisOldName) ) 
UpdateRecord = true;
}  // oldname?
```

Still in the loop, I update, if appropriate

```
<cfif UpdateRecord>
<cfquery datasource="#dsn#">
update doctor
set name = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" value="#ThisName#">

where doctorid = <cfqueryparam cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" value="#ThisId#">
</cfquery>
</cfif>

</cfloop>  <!--- form fields --->
```

I've used other approaches that were similar but not identical.  All of them loop through the list of form fields and identify "ThisId".

By the way, safetext is a function on cflib.org you may find useful.